# How to make Ubuntu 20.04 ask for password only at log in?

Tags: 20.04

How to make Ubuntu ask for password only at log in, and not when the screen goes blank or computer suspends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open gnome settings and go to the Privacy tab. From there, go to "Screen Lock" and enable/disable whatever setting you want (in your case, disable "Automatic Screen Lock" and "Lock Screen on Suspend").

Comment: You are right, don't know though why I missed it...